# Dynamically altering object types on instantiation

Tags: python

I have a MetaClass that, at the moment, simply returns an obj of a class.

From this MetaClass, I derieved two different classes. The difference in the classes is a dictionary that gets passed to `__init__` for one of the classes but not for the other one.

If this dict only contains one single entry, I want python to return an instance of the other class instead of the one that was actually called.

```
class _MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        return super(_MetaClass, cls).__new__(name, bases, **dct)

class Class1(object):
    __metaclass__ = _MetaClass

    def __init__(self, someargs):
        pass

class Class2(object):
    __metaclass__ = _MetaClass

    def __init__(self, someargs, kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) == 1:
            return Class1(someargs)
        else:
            pass

TestInstance = Class2("foo", {"bar":"foo"})    #should now be Class1 instance because only one item in dct
```

If the dict, like in this case, has only `len(dct) == 1`, then it should create an instance of Class1 with the "foo" passed to its `__init__` instead of returning an instance of Class2 as it normally would

I tried to implement the `__new__` and `__init__` methods for the MetaClass, but I could not figure out how to check the arguments that are actually passes on new class instantiation

Answer (score 0):

You could create a handlerMethod to deal with the issue

```
def handler(yourDict):
    if len(yourDict) == 1:
         return Class2(yourDict)
     else:
         return Class1(yourDict)
```

and then call the handler instead of the constructor

```
TestInstance = handler(yourDict)
```